# log4rs error Log4rs(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" })

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement log4rs by following [the docs](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.8.0/log4rs/). My goal is to put the result of `info!("INFO")` into the file requests.log, but I get an error:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
>   value: Log4rs(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or
>   directory" })', libcore/result.rs:945:5

I have the following files in the src folder:

```
- main.rs
- log4rs.yml
- requests.log
```

main.rs:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
extern crate log4rs;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    log4rs::init_file("log4rs.yml", Default::default()).unwrap();
    info!("INFO");
}
```

the config file log4rs.yml:

```
# Scan this file for changes every 30 seconds
refresh_rate: 30 seconds

appenders:
  # An appender named "stdout" that writes to stdout
  stdout:
    kind: console

  # An appender named "requests" that writes to a file with a custom pattern encoder
  requests:
    kind: file
    path: "requests.log"
    encoder:
      pattern: "{d} - {m}{n}"

# Set the default logging level to "warn" and attach the "stdout" appender to the root
root:
  level: warn
  appenders:
    - stdout

loggers:
  # Raise the maximum log level for events sent to the "app::backend::db" logger to "info"
  app::backend::db:
    level: info

  # Route log events sent to the "app::requests" logger to the "requests" appender,
  # and *not* the normal appenders installed at the root
  app::requests:
    level: info
    appenders:
      - requests
    additive: false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type `cargo run`, your working directory is the current directory. This means that all your relative paths will depend on this working directory.

For example, if you are in your home directory (`~`) and you have your  project folder named `foo`. When you go in it, that gives you `~/foo`. If you now type `cargo run`, that means that when `log4rs` tries to open your file it will try to open the file `~/foo/log4rs.yml`. The file is not here but in `~/foo/src/log4rs.yml`

You have many solutions:

- `log4rs::init_file("src/log4rs.yml", Default::default()).unwrap();`
- move `log4rs.yml` to `foo`
- use an absolute path (not a good solution for your current case)